# Additive graphs code

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, code-request, drawing, pathfinding

For $n\geq 1$ the fibonacci sum graph on the set $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ denoted by $G_n$, is the graph with vertex set $[n]$ and edge set $\{uv, u+v=F_i, \text{for some}\quad i\}$.  I wrote the Mathematica Code for this graph as follow:

[image]

I was dealing with the some problems today!

First, I wanna to draws and determine the Spanning paths of this graph as following picture[image].

How can I Highlight or determine it in Mathematica? I know In graph $G_{F_k}$, where $F_k$ is Fibonacci numbers, this spanning paths are produced with edges that having sums in $\{F_{k-1}, F_k, F_{k+1}\}$ and also at most has two spanning paths.

In the second question, I want to draw this graph for each set as follows:

Let $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ be a set. We define additive graph $A_n$ with the vertices set $A=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$  and $(i,j)$ is a edge in $A_n$ if and only if $u+v \in A$.

How can I write Mathematica code of the $A_n$ graph?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! First, I would ask you to copy the code from Mathematica and paste it in your question (instead of providing a screenshot). In that way it is easier for others to run your code. Second, do you know about functions [`FindSpanningTree`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSpanningTree.html) and [`HihglightGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HihglightGraph.html)? Lastly, you should put a semicolon (`;`) before `Graph` (after your `For` loop).

Comment: @Domen Thanks Domen.  Right. These functions were ok. I am a bit problem for drawing my second question.(Drawing A_n graph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html)

```
ClearAll[additiveGraph]
additiveGraph[a_List, b_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 RelationGraph[MemberQ[# + #2] @ b &, a, a, opts]
```

***Examples:***

```
FIB = Fibonacci /@ Range[100];

additiveGraph[Range@13, FIB, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Remove self-loops and and add desired options:

```
g1 = SimpleGraph @
  additiveGraph[Range @ 13, FIB,   
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[White, 12],
   EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Red, 14],
   EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> First@PositionIndex[FIB][e[[1]] + e[[2]]]},
   ImageSize -> 900, PlotTheme -> "NameLabeled", VertexSize -> .4,
   VertexStyle -> FaceForm[{Opacity[.7], Black}], 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Orange, AbsoluteThickness[35], 
     CapForm["Round"]]]
```

[image]

Find a hamiltonian path using [`FindHamiltonianPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHamiltonianPath.html):

```
hamiltonianpath = UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[FindHamiltonianPath @ g1, 2, 1];
```

Highlight `hamiltonianpath` using [`HighlightGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightGraph.html):

```
HighlightGraph[SetProperty[g1, 
  EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[Cyan, 16]], hamiltonianpath]
```

[image]

Use [`LineGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineGraph.html) with desired options:

```
LineGraph[g1, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much . How can I Draw the $A_n$ graph? Actually replace Fibonacci sequence with  vertex set $A$. and two vertices are adjacent if and only if $u+v\in A$?

Comment: try  `additiveGraph[A, A]`